# Display issues on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: display, 16.04

I've recently installed Ubuntu 16.04 LTS on my laptop alongside Windows 10. It has Intel HD 5500 graphics as well as an AMD Radeon R5 M230 chip. My display is not the way it should be. It's kind of spread out. It is of the kind you get once you install a fresh copy of Windows without installing the Intel drivers, though I know that Intel graphics drivers and AMD open source drivers come pre-installed with Ubuntu 16.04. My max screen resolution as available in the System Settings -> Displays -> Resolution is 1366 x 768 (16:9), which is already selected. How do I fix this issue and get proper display?

Also, when I do this: lspci -nn | grep VGA, I get this: 00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 5500 [8086:1616] (rev 09). Does this mean Ubuntu can't recognise the AMD graphics card?  Also, hardware_info.html has a part, which I think is somehow related to the AMD graphics chip. [hardware_info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k6nWb.png)

Refer to the attached image link, though it may not be very evident from the same. [screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0XHew.png)

Answer (score 1):

AMD and Ubuntu 16.04LTS ... there are currently known issues. Check this out [HERE](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2016/03/ubuntu-drops-amd-catalyst-fglrx-driver-16-04)

Comment: Thanks for the link, but I've already read it. The Intel graphics should be enough to give a proper display, but it's not. As I've already mentioned before, I have a stretched display.